# Symfony 3 - custom user provider - login always showing "bad credentials" instead of "username not found"

Tags: authentication, symfony, credentials

I am developing my first project in symfony 3. I implemented a custom user provider like described in the symfony documentation. Login is working perfect, but when i type in a user that does not exist i always get the error message "bad credentials". I would love to show the message that is declared in the usernamenotfound exeption, but its not working. If i add "hide_user_not_found:  false" in my security.yml i get the message "username could not be found" but i want to show the message i have in my code (Username "%s" does not exist.). I would also like to implement CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException but thats the second part of the question. I hope somebody can help me! Here is the code... Thanks!!!

Code is exactly the same like here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html

File: src/AppBundle/Security/User/WebserviceUser.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

class WebserviceUser implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $salt;
    private $roles;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $salt, array $roles)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->salt !== $user->getSalt()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

File: src/AppBundle/Security/User/WebserviceUserProvider.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\User;

use AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // make a call to your webservice here
        $userData = ...
        // pretend it returns an array on success, false if there is no user

        if ($userData) {
            $password = '...';

            // ...

            return new WebserviceUser($username, $password, $salt, $roles);
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return WebserviceUser::class === $class;
    }
}
```

File: src\AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;



use AppBundle\Controller\BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser;


class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */

        public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {

        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');



        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error
        ));
    }


}
```

File: app\Resources\views\security\login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}



    <div class="wrapper fullscreen">

        <div class="image_full">

        </div>
        <div class="small_content">
            <a href="" class="logo_small"></a>






            <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">

                {% if error %}
                    <p class="text-danger text-center">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</p>
                {% endif %}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email-Adresse</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Passwort</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Passwort" name="_password">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 left">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default green btn_full">Anmelden</button>
                    <!--<a class="btn btn-default green btn_full" href="">Anmelden</a>-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 right">
                    <a class="btn btn-default green btn_full" href="{{ path('register') }}">Registrieren</a>
                </div>
                <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default green btn_full">Einloggen</button>-->

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



{% endblock %}
```

File: app\config\security.yml

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        #in_memory:
            #memory: ~
        webservice:
                    id: app.webservice_user_provider

    hide_user_not_found:  false
    #erase_credentials:    true
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        #dev:
           # pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
           # security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

    encoders:
            AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser: plaintext
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware of two ways of changing that `Bad credentials.` error message:

1)

```
# AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml:
# or you can put this in app/Resources/translations/message.en.yml - has the same effect
"Bad credentials.": "Your custom error message here."

# app/Resources/Security/login.html.twig
...
{% if error %}
    <div class="error">{{ error.message|trans }}</div>
{% endif %}

# app/config/config.yml, where %locale%, in this case, is set to "en"
framework:
    translator: { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

2)

```
# login.html.twig
{% if error %}
    <div>
    {{ error.message|replace({"Bad credentials.":"Your custom error message here."}) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

You can try one of these two and see which one fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not the solution i want. I need the possibility for custom error messages that are technical correct for different cases. Like username not found or for example email not verified etc. Is this possible whitout using guard?